# bitmapStrokeString not working in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am doing a CG project in openGL using glut in C++ and I need to get a text as output but I am getting this error but it works fine when written in C:

[image: error]

So how can I make it work for C++ or is there any other way of printing text in glut.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string.h>


GLdouble width,height;
int wd;
int xc,yc;
void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    width=(GLdouble) w;
    height=(GLdouble) h;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) width, (GLsizei) height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,width,0.0,height);
}
void draw_score(long long int score)
{
        long long int tempsc = score;
     char str[15];



      //  glRasterPos2f(0.1, 0.5);
        glutStrokeString(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN,"hii");
}
void display(void)
{
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glPushMatrix();
    //glTranslatef(1280/2.0-250,600/2.0-250,0);

long long a1=2;
  glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(200,300,0.0);
            glScalef(0.2,0.2,1);
            draw_score(a1);
        glPopMatrix();

   glFlush ();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);

    glutCreateWindow ("hello");
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
        glutDisplayFunc(display);


        // OpenGL init
        //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? You posted an image instead of actual code, you didn't include the error message, or anything else. You should include (as TEXT) a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead and everything else mentioned.

Comment: Transcribe that image of the error to text & edit it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glutStrokeString()` is a [FreeGLUT/OpenGLUT extension](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) to [the GLUT spec](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node75.html):

> 3.4 Differences from GLUT 3.7
>
> ...
>
> 3.4.5 String Rendering
>
> New functions have been added to render full character strings
>   (including carriage returns) rather than rendering one character at a
>   time. More functions return the widths of character strings and the
>   font heights, in pixels for bitmapped fonts and in OpenGL units for
>   the stroke fonts.

Use `freeglut.h` instead of `glut.h` to pull in the declaration.